# Not sure why i get the "error: does not name a type "

Tags: c++

the problem wants me to print the value in the array that is the most frequent, im stuck at this point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int dupe(int arr1[], int nElements);  

int value;  
    for (int i =0; i < nElements; i++)
    {
        value = arr1[i];

            for (int j =i+1; j<nElements; j++)
            {
                if (value==arr[j])
                        return value;
            }
    } 




int main()
{
int arr1[] ={5,1,6,3,1}, nElements;  

nElements= sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int);

cout<<dupe(arr1,nElements);



}
```

i keep getting a compilier error that says :

```
9:9: error: expected unqualified-id before 'for'
9:24: error: 'i' does not name a type
9:36: error: 'i' does not name a type
```

not sure why
any help would be useful

Comment: You need to put your code in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int dupe(int arr1[], int nElements)
{
    int value;
    for(int i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
    {
        value = arr1[i];

        for(int j = i + 1; j < nElements; j++)
        {
            if(value == arr[j])
                return value;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = { 5, 1, 6, 3, 1 }, nElements;

    nElements = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(int);

    cout << dupe(arr1, nElements);
}
```

The function dupe does find the first duplicate, which in this case is the target value, but not always.

Perhaps a better approach would be to sort the array (using std::sort in the algorithms header). This would make all duplicates adjacent and therefore easy to count.